# Make div height auto adjust proportionally

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, height

On this page... http://www.gogeye.com/eomnew/eom-success/  I have 50% wide divs which are split again into 40% and 60%. The left portion contains an image and therefore will adjust its height automatically when the brower window is shrunk. I would like the right side which contains text and a background image to also decrease its height when this happens but don't know of any way to implement this

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The right side seems to shrink proportionately already. Also, please post the relevant code here, in your question.

Comment: The button repositions because it has a fixed position but if you look at the stripey grey background which contains the text it doesn't. I would like the bottom of that to meet the bottom of the image at all times. I'll add code now.

Comment: I'd give "equal height columns" a search.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it (in a way), by adding a massive amount of padding to the bottom, then the same amount of negative margin.

I then made the parent div overflow:hidden

```
.success (parent) {
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
}

.testipic {
width:40%;
float:left;
}

.testirest {
margin-bottom: -99999px;
padding-bottom: 99999px;
width:60%;
float:right;
background-image:url('img/lines-light.png');
}
```